# Static header menu using angular material

Tags: angular-material, angular-cli

Problem:

I'm trying to get a static header menu component using angular material similar to that at the top of the [Angular material site](https://material.angular.io/). Is this possible to do with any of the material components or not, please can any one help with a custom one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[Mat-Toolbar Component](https://material.angular.io/components/toolbar/examples)** from Angular Material.

Exploited `css-properties` and `html-markup` to achieve the static header.

**Approach :**

1.Give `height:100%, width: 100%` to `html,body`and your app component (root component). 

2. Make two container - one `header` and other `content-container`. 

3. Give `height: 50px` to `header`, and remaining height ie `calc( 100% - 50px)` to `content-container`.

```
    -------- app.component.ts--------
    <section class="app-container">
       <header>
           <mat-toolbar color="primary">
              Static Header
           </mat-toolbar>
       </header>
       <section class="content-container">
          <p>Paragraph with content overflowing data</p>
       </section>
    </section>
-------------------------------------------------------------
      html, body, .app-container {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          height: 100%;
          width: 100%;
       }

        mat-toolbar {
          height: 100% !important;
        }    

        .app-container header {
          height: 50px;
          max-height: 50px;
          box-shadow: 0 3px 5px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.2), 
                      0 6px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.14), 
                      0 1px 18px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.12);
        }
        .app-container .content-container {
          height: calc( 100% - 50px);
          overflow: auto;
          padding: 10px;
          word-break: break-all;
        }
```

**[Stackblitz-Demo with Static Header using Angular Toolbar component](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-toolbar-static-toolbar-header?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: I am glad, i was helpful.